# I transferred BTC from mtgox and they have disappeared - What should/can I do?

Tags: transactions, security

I sent 3 btc from mtgox to cavirtex. The address used is correct and I was given a transaciton ID by mtgox. Yet blockchain.info shows no record of a transaction and 3 btc are missing.
I have written to both mtgox and cavirtex to ask about them - still no replies.

What can I do? How do I know if they have been stolen?

This question with an accepted answer is related - or more to the point mine is a duplicate of it:
[Transaction not found](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9534/transaction-not-found?rq=1)

Comment: Why would you write to cavirtex? To ask them why they didn't credit you for a transaction that has no confirmations?

Comment: Because they might know what I can do/try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the transaction is in the list of [unconfirmed transctions](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions). If it's not, then the sender is at fault, Mt Gox in your case. If it is, then just be patient. It can take awhile for a transaction to get included by a miner.

Comment: Thanks - the transaction is not in the list of unconfirmed transactions. What should I tell MtGox? What is the most likely reason for this happening?

Comment: @val You should tell Gox that they haven't performed your withdrawal and they need to do so. It's hard to know why it's happening without knowing about Gox's internal procedures. Since you have the transaction ID, they must already know what funds they're going to use, so it's hard to imagine why they wouldn't have released the transaction. (I have a theory though. If I'm right, when the withdrawals does happen, it will not have the transaction ID you were given.)

Comment: Thanks again. I'll do that. They have been deducted from the balance at Mt Gox. nether space...

Comment: Maybe the transaction id is just an internal transaction id and not a bitcoin transacion id. I have reviewed my withdrawals and in the accoun history you can see the address and in the emails there is a code but it is not a bitcoin transaction id.

Comment: @frisco Ahh, then they probably just haven't processed it yet.

Comment: @frisco Yes I noticed this code vs transaction ID difference you speak of too. (wow - awkward wording)